# How can I prompt users while running a playbook?

Tags: ansible, interactive

My needs: Write a playbook which can install apache if the user wants to, while the playbook is running by typing yes or no.

> apache_prompt.yml

```
  hosts: slaves  
  vars_prompt:
    - name: install_apache
      prompt: "Do yo want to install apache? (yes/no)?"

  tasks:
    - name: if 'yes'
      include_tasks: apache.yml
      when: install_apache == 'yes'
```

> apache.yml

```
---
 - name: apache install
   apt:
     name: apache2
     state: present
```

These playbooks are integrated in a role folder "apache"

> My /tasks/main.yml

```
---
- import_tasks: apache_prompt.yml
```

> My main playbook, which I use for installing some stuffs thanks to roles:

---

```
 - hosts: slaves
   roles:
      - ntp
      - nmap
      - tcpdump
      - unattended-upgrades
      - apache
```

I only have trouble with the apache role.

------------------EDIT-------------------

I've got syntax error since I wrote my question. I tried to modify the

> apache_prompt.yml

until now and i got this error:  ERROR! no action detected in task. This often indicates a misspelled module name, or incorrect module path.

```
---
- hosts: slaves
  vars_prompt:
    - name: "install_apache"
      prompt: "Do yo want to install apache? (yes/no)?"

  tasks:
    - include_tasks: apache.yml
      when: install_apache == 'yes'
```

Comment: Welcome to U&L. You haven't specified what your question exactly is. You seem to have already set the prompts using the 'apache_prompt.yml' file. Is there a problem with this configuration?

Comment: I assume your problem lies within the check `when: install_apache == 'yes'`, is that correct?

Comment: I edited my question. My playbook contains syntax errors

Comment: @Ludo. Check syntax with "ansible-lint <playbook>".

Comment: @VladimirBotka Finally i wrote an another playbook. He runs like a charm when lauched with ansible-playbook /path_to_playbook/playbook.yml but i get a error when i run my main playbook which contains the roles. i tried "ansible-lint my_main_playbook" and it say "(no action detected in task. This often indicates a misspelled module name, or incorrect module path.)"

Comment: @Ludo. Where is my_main_playbook? Put the info into the question. Check the indentation. Follow [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).